# drupalSettings object not showing for anonymous users. core/drupalSettings is added as a library dependency

Tags: views, theming, javascript

I'm stumped on this one. I’m having an issue where the `drupalSettings` object is empty when not logged in. Works fine when I am authenticated. `- core/drupalSettings` is in theme’s *.libraries.yml file.

I've tried

- Cleared cache (1million times).
- Triple checked the YAML indentation
- Verified that the settings are being added when stepping through via Xdebug
- The JS file that I'm adding is via ['# attached'] works great

What am I missing here? Where to start troubleshooting? I'll owe  if someone can help point me in the right direction.

themename.libraries.yml

```
views-load-more:
  js:
    js/views-load-more.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupalSettings
```

In my themename.theme

```
function themename_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  if (!empty($variables["pager"])) {
    $view_selector = '.view-' . $variables["id"] . '.view-display-id-' . $variables["display_id"];
    $view_content_selector = $view_selector . ' .view-content';
    $view_pager_selector = $view_selector . ' .pager';

    $variables["view_array"]["#attached"]["library"][] = 'themename/views-load-more';
    $variables["view_array"]['#attached']['drupalSettings']['themename']['viewsLoadMore']['viewSelector'] = $view_selector;
    $variables["view_array"]['#attached']['drupalSettings']['themename']['viewsLoadMore']['viewContentSelector'] = $view_content_selector;
    $variables["view_array"]['#attached']['drupalSettings']['themename']['viewsLoadMore']['viewPagerSelector'] = $view_pager_selector;
  }
}
```

Note that the `themename/views-load-more`library does get attached when anonymous (I can see the JS file within it).

And also note that this works perfectly when authenticated. This tells me that the drupalSettings dependency isn't working even though I'm declaring this.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 7):

Solved the issue... and the answer is *weird*...

within the `html.html.twig` file, we have a `<div class="body-inner">` tag that wrapped the `<js-bottom-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}">` placeholder.

For whatever #drupalWTF reason, if this placeholder tag is wrapped inside of a div, `drupalSettings` will load an empty object. Once I moved it directly underneath the `body` tag, it worked fine.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: You are a life saver, I've spent almost a week trying to understand what could be the issue!

Comment: Oh wow, I had this too, but it was caused *after design* by an un-closed `<strong>` in a certain summarised (broken off after n characters) news item at the bottom of the page which caused the browser to wrap a `<strong>` around the the script elements in question resulting in the same problem (which especially manifested itself by a broken behaviour, namely Juicebox image gallery not loading).

Comment: Unfortunately, this just breaks my page. But I'm in Drupal 9 now.

Answer (score 2):

Add `core/drupal` as a dependency.

**themename.libraries.yml**

```
views-load-more:
  js:
    js/views-load-more.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
```

Comment: Good thought, but still no go. `core/drupal` was being loaded by a separate library. Just to be 100% certain, I added it as a dependency - but no luck. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Tip: look for other javascript errors happening on the page. If a JS error happens before the assignment of `drupalSettings`, it will not be initiated.